# Should I use XML for message communication?

Tags: xml

I have to build an integrated application in which three processes have to
communicate with each other through message communication. Messages are very
small just like commands. I don't know much about XML. Should option of 
using XML for message communication be used or it is better to send message
in form of structures & receiving entity reads that structured message field-wise
& interprets accordingly. Please guide.

Pratap Malik

Comment: What language are the programs written in? And what kind of messages? Process pipes or networking?

Comment: If both parts of the applications use the same data structure and there would be no reformatting or parsing involved, I see no reason to transform them into something else before sending. If the messages are very small and have no complicated structure, XML is overkill. And if there is no need to communicate with other processes than just your own applications, you don't need XML. And if performance or timing is an issue, don't use XML. And if you have no need to save the messages to disk and edit them manually, why choose a bloated format like XML? Hm, can't think of anything in favour of XML

Answer (score 2):

First of all ! **Good question** ! Generally people thinks about this but they took decisions.

Now your question have two answer

1) *Yes* ! If you **want to keep history** of your communicated messages as well the processes.

2) *No* ! If you **don't provide history**. No need to make any file. Just keep in session (if you want) until process runs

---> I prefer 1st option because from the history you can get data of your past. And another main thing is that no need of session maintenance (so server memory saved ! A little bit ! but memory is memory) ! And another reason is XML is very lightweight and custom tagged !